# Create an Array of object on each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Eventually I am hoping to get an object to display like this:

```
'0': {
       '0': {
              label: 'Book:',
              content: 'a book name',        
       }, 

       '1': {
              label: 'Video:',
              content: 'a video name',        
       }, 

       '2': {
              label: 'Audio:',
              content: 'an audio name',        
       },              
  }, 

'1': {
       '0': {
              label: 'Book:',
              content: 'another book name',        
       }, 

       '1': {
              label: 'Video:',
              content: 'another video name',        
       }, 

       '2': {
              label: 'Audio:',
              content: 'another audio name',        
       },              
  }
```

My code in  http://jsfiddle.net/ScbjL/4/ didn't turn out right, I'm puzzled why objDL is undefined?

Comment: It is undefined because `objDT.label` is undefined. you need to specify a key to select the correct object to pull the label from.

Comment: Also the next line has the same issue with objDD - looks like you're missing a subscript objDD[i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not iterate over `.container`s, `dt`s and `dd`s separately - you are forgetting from which container the objDT/DD is stemming. Also use an array instead of an object for the results.

```
var objDL = [];
$("dl").each(function(i) {
    objDL[i] = [];
    $(this).children("dt").each(function(j) {
        var $this = $(this);
        objDL[i][j] = {
            title: $this.text(),
            description: $this.next("dd").text();
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: the i only loops twice, where there are three sets of dt/dd. Could it be the loop closure issue where I need to figure out how to maintain the index value of m & n in objDL loop?

Comment: Right, you want to group them by their `.container`, I missed that. Yet that would be very complicated since `objDT` and `objDD` did not distinguish that. See my snippet on how to do it without those

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks for the help! is objDL[i][j] a multidimensional array?

Comment: @user1824996: Yeah, it's an array of arrays of objects - just the structure you described with plain objects.